# Can't add textview name inside a container view in storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin, storyboard, uitextview

I added a container view on a view and added a textview inside it.
The app compiles and run with no problem.
But when I add a name to the textview I receive that error when the app is launched:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSUnknownKeyException Reason: [<SaisieVocale 0x13d929f50> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key mavariablename.
```

I don't understand the problem, does someone have an idea ?

EDIT: Note, if I move the textview from the contained view to the main view there's no error.

EDIT, extract of my storyboard:

```
<textView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" textAlignment="natural" id="78070" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" customClass="MyTextView" keyboardDismissMode="onDrag">
                            <rect key="frame" x="30" y="43" width="354" height="142"/>
                            <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                            <string key="text">text</string>
                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                            <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits" autocapitalizationType="sentences"/>
                            <color key="textColor" colorSpace="calibratedRGB" red="0.22745098039215686" green="0.41176470588235292" blue="0.8" alpha="1"/>

</textView>
<connections>
            <outlet property="mavariablename" destination="78070" id="name-outlet-78070"/>
</connections>
```

Comment: What is __mavariablename__?

Comment: Show the code of how things are setup in particular how you 'add a name to the textview'.

Comment: mavariablename is the name I add. I add the name in the storyboard, see my edit

Comment: did I say a swearword ?

Comment: @Entretoize Why do you ask?

Comment: Because I had no answer after adding what some asked me to do, but no problem...

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem (actualy it works).
I'm using xamarin and when I need a textview to be connected to a variable in the view controller class file, I just have to add a name in the properties of the uitextview component in the storyboard. So I didn't know a file was created containing the declaration of the variable like with swift.

The problem was that this declaration wasn't created for some reason, so I added it and now it works.